# Objective-C property

Tags: iphone, properties, retain

I'm developing an Iphone app. I read from a book about declaring a property like below:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listData;
```

Then in the implementation file, dealloc method, must put something like:

```
[listData release];
```

I wonder if I declare as

```
@property NSArray *listData;
```

do I have to release it? It'll save 1 line of code for me.

Comment: I'd stick to retain+release. I think the compiler may complain about you not specifying the retaining/assigning bit in the property; even if it doesn't, most of the time, `assign` is not really what you want.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler gives a warning, something not specified, assign is used. OK, so for property I'll use retain+release. But for private variables, I won't create property for them. Do I need to release the private variables? TIA

Comment: after some reading, I understand now, cmiiw:
1. copy is used for NSString *
2. for other object, retain is used
3. both must be released in dealloc method
4. for primitive data types, assign is used, no need to release

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to release it. The retain qualifier means that when you set the property, your class will call retain on the NSArray. When your class is done, you need to release anything that you have retained, otherwise you have a memory leak.

Comment: Hi, understood. But if I don't use retain, do I need to release it? Will I have a problem if I don't use retain?

Comment: It seems that you did't get vincent's question.

Answer (score -1):

```
@property NSArray *listData;
```

will just  implicitly declare your accessor and mutator methods for listData,

but what about memory management(it's a serious stuff as far as  iphone app development is concerned)?

If you going to use it in implementation then you should release it in dealloc method

also refer [Official Apple docs for @property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html)